# How to use jquery and javascript in same document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, call

So I am trying to use jQuery, (in the heading) and javascript (normally) in the same document, but it seems that because of the script source thing, it conflicts with the JavaScript  and doesn't word as I need it too

```
<head>
<title> Panel </title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="clicker.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
(function( $ ){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#buckhead").click(function(){
            $("#buckpanel").slideToggle(750);
        });
    });
})( jQuery );
</script>
</head>
```

Then later on in the document I put:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var bcost = 1;
var clickmulti = 1;
var clicks = 0;
var bcost = 1000;
var mcost = 100;
var y = 0;
var x = 0;
document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
document.getElementById("mcost").innerHTML = mcost;
document.getElementById("bcost").innerHTML = bcost;
function clickFunc() {
    clicks += cps * clickmulti;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    return true;
}
function clickMulti() {
    if(clicks >= mcost && y < 50) {
        clicks -= mcost;
        mcost *= 1.25;
        mcost = math.ceil(mcost * 1) / 1;
        clickmulti += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
        document.getElementById("mcost").innerHTML = mcost;
        y += 1;
        return true;
    } else if(y == 50) {
    alert("This upgrade is maxed!");
    return false;
    } else {
        alert("You do not have enough fish to purchase this!");
        return false;
    }
}
function clickBase() {
    if(clicks >= bcost && x < 100) {
        clicks -= bcost;
        bcost *= 1.25;
        bcost = math.ceil(bcost * 1) / 1;
        x += 1;
        cps += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
        document.getElementById("bcost").innerHTML = bcost;
        return true;
    } else if(x == 100) {
        alert("This upgrade is maxed!");
        return false;
    } else {
        alert("You do not have enough fish to purchase this!");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

And it seems like the code is conflicting, because the jQuery is working just fine, as it is simple code, but the buttons to activate the JavaScript, which should be working as buttons are really easy, seems so when I click it, the functions aren't working, although almost every function is working, (ALMOST) except for

```
function clickFunc()
```

If you have the answer it would be greatly appreciated!
edit: here is the button calls, which by the way the buttons are before the second script.

```
<div class="fish"
    <h2>Click for fish</h2><br>
    <button onclick="clickFunc()" type="button">Click for fish</button><br>
    <p> You have <span id="clicks"></span> fish</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="clickMulti()"> Upgrade your click multiplier!  (Cost:<span id="mcost"></span>)</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="clickBase()">Upgrade base clicks!<br>
(Cost:<span id="bcost"></span>)</button>
</div><br><br>
```

Comment: Can you share more of your DOM? Specifically where the <button> tags are, and how you attach them to these functions.

Comment: Depending upon where your second lot of JAvaScript is in relation to the HTML I would say that you are getting an error at line document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks; because these elements don't exist at the time of code execution.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, simply my problem of forgetting to make a global variable instead of a local variable. I forgot to make the global variable "cps"